# Laravel Forms Proper Syntax

Tags: php, forms, laravel

So it took my time and bored me so much and I wanted to ask you!

```
   <select>
     @foreach($items as $item)
     <option value="{{$item->name}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
     @endforeach
   </select>
```

I am ok with this example i mean i can get items in dropdown list. But! When I try to do it in laravel forms, I cant make the same! I cant place the foreach loop inside of forms of laravel

```
<div class="form-group">
     @foreach($items as $item)
    {!! Form::select('name', [$item->name => $item->name]) !!}
    @endforeach
</div>
```

So in the end i get this.. [difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW1zx.png)

https://pasteboard.co/GRYceaG.png

I know that i need to put this foreach loop after select in `{!! Form::select('name',`but i cant do it! Help me about this damn stupid problem please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form::select` creates a `<select>`. So you create a `<select>` on every iteration. Instead, you need to:

```
{!! Form::select('name', $options) !!}
```

where `$options` is array with your values. You can create this array in a controller.

For example, you can `pluck` required field from collection and pass the result array to `select()`:

```
$options = $user->items()->pluck('name');

{!! Form::select('name', $options) !!}
```

Comment: See the example here: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#drop-down-lists

Comment: look i get this array as $items = $user->items()->get();

but i need to take name of every item, but its not working in view ..

Comment: i checked all of these examples just i am very angry to this thing that i can do it in normal html form but cant do same thing in laravel form... shouldnt they be the same?

Comment: I suppose you need to `pluck` required column, something like: `$items = $user->items()->pluck('name')`.

Comment: MULDER I THINK IT WORKED BRO, I WILL CHECK AND TELL YOU.

Comment: i did mate! thank you again, you can edit your answer about pluck.